# C++11 integer initalization

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the following code correct from a *C++ standard viewpoint*?

Or do any of the cases outputting `0` in my example fail under certain circumstances?

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() : k(), t{} {}
  uint64_t i; //Uninitalized
  uint64_t k;
  uint64_t t;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  uint64_t i;
  std::cout << i << std::endl; //Outputs garbage
  uint64_t k = uint64_t();
  std::cout << k << std::endl; //Outputs 0
  uint64_t t = {};
  std::cout << t << std::endl; //Outputs 0

  //

  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.i << std::endl; //Outputs garbage
  std::cout << foo.k << std::endl; //Outputs 0
  std::cout << foo.t << std::endl; //Outputs 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k()` and `uint64_t k = uint64_t()` is [`value-initialized`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.4) that will then be zero:

> (8.4) Otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

`t{}` and `uint64_t t = {}` is [`list-initialized`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#1) that will default to zero.

Since `Foo::i` and `uint64_t i` is uninitialized, it will have an indeterminate value.

From [dcl.init/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#12):

> When storage for an object with automatic or dynamic storage duration
>   is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate value**, and if *no
>   initialization* is performed for the object, that object retains an
>   indeterminate value until that value is replaced ([expr.ass])